# css transition renders canvas useless

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

I'm in the process of creating an interactive whiteboard application using PHP and jQuery. Creating a deck is not the issue, nor is applying a canvas overlay to the page so that I can write on it. I'm an amateur coder and completely self-taught. This is part an exercise in learning more, and part a means to give me a great tool to use in my teaching practice.

The problem that I'm encountering is applying a CSS transition to the canvas element, so that as the slides change, the canvas element moves as well, in order to avoid having the previously made drawings still present on new slides.

I have gotten the canvas element to move with the slide transition, however, when this happens, the canvas is rendered useless (on the current slide). If I transition back to the previous slide, I can see everything I've drawn.

I'm hoping that this isn't too vague of a question or explanation of the situation to get help, but any pointers would be great.

Comment: Any relevant code?

Comment: "useless" is a useless description (pun intended)! Please describe, in detail, what is happening (wrong) and how you would like it to be.

Comment: @markE I've created a slide deck. The container for all of the slides is calculated to the width of all of the slides combined. When the slides transition (using translateX), the canvas element should transition with the slide and move right or left by the same amount. The slide and the canvas element do move in tandem, but when the canvas element moves, whatever is drawn on it after the transition now appears on the now-hidden part of the canvas. Ultimately, I'd like for whatever is drawn to appear on the new slide.

Comment: @markE You can see what I'm talking about by going to mygrad.es/slides.html. Left and right arrows control the deck right now. Draw something on the first slide, move to the next, draw again, then return to the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem. I thought the original script was taking into account the distance the slides were transitioning, but it wasn't. I added in a line to take care of this, and it works like a charm.